# Parse send an image in Cloud Code as parameter

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to send a picture as a parameter without saving before in Parse. I use the javascriptSDK

```
Parse.Cloud.run("saveImage", { photo:???, title:title, description:description}).then(function(result) {
}, function(error) {});
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Parse wants you to save images as a PFFile and then, add the PFFile to your object.

Comment: because all saves in the app are made in the Cloud code. I do it to avoid errors on the client side. There are other possibilities?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "errors on the client side" ?

Comment: I mean I want to have the entire method of saving in the cloud. This is because I have multiple clients on multiple platforms and want to have a single method for all.

Comment: Then please see my answer

Comment: Your answer refers to ios, not javascript

Answer (score 0):

You upload the image data as parameter of your cloud code function, e.g. with iOS SDK:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "uploadImage", withParameters: ["imageData": image.highQualityJPEGData]]) { (response, error) in
    ...
}
```

On the server you save the image file:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("uploadImage", function(request, response) {

    var imageData = request.params.imageData;
    var imageFile = new Parse.File("image.png", imageData, "image/png");

    imageFile.save(null, {useMasterKey: true})
    .then(
        function() {
            response.success();
        }, 
        function(error) {
            response.error(error.message);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your UIImage to NSData, and save it as an attribute of your object.

Parse does not recommend storing large pieces of binary data like images or documents using NSData fields on PFObject. PFObjects should not exceed 128 kilobytes in size. To store more, Parse recommends you use PFFile.

If you really want to create your object in the Cloud code, you will need to create the PFFile from the cloud code, save it, add it to the object, and save the object.